# Environment in Jenkins Pipeline has no variables

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Because I couldn't use an environment variable that I thought should exist, I printed all the environment variables in my Jenkins Pipeline script:

```
node {

  for(e in env) {
     print "key = ${e.key}, value = ${e.value}"
  }

}
```

This prints:

`key = null, value = null`

I'm very surprised by this.

Why are there no environment variables?

Comment: maybe it's just not iterable? or just another side-effect of CPS. Try `sh "set"`.

Comment: `sh` doesn't work: `nohup: failed to run command "sh": No such file or directory`

Comment: What OS is the node running?

Comment: Red Hat Linux. `/bin/sh` doesn't work either

Comment: no.. that's not a command, it's part of the DSL.
use `node { sh "set" }`.

Comment: For `node { sh "set" }`, I get `nohup: failed to run command "sh": No such file or directory`. @StephenKing do you know what could cause this?

Comment: That's very weird. And you use this as your Pipeline script? And you are really on Linux? Do you have some weird chrooted or something'd Jenkins setup?

Comment: No chroot and I'm not sure what you mean regarding the Jenkins setup.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug/limitation. If you [look at the implementation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/EnvActionImpl.java), there is no support for iteration.

The following works as a workaround:

```
node {
  for(e in env.getEnvironment()) {
     print "key = ${e.key}, value = ${e.value}"
  }
}
```